# List all available fonts in SwiftUI for macOS

Tags: swift, swiftui, appkit, nsfont

I know how to do this for iOS but I can't figure out how to do it for macOS.

```
let allFontNames = UIFont.familyNames.flatMap { UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: $0) }

 var body: some View {
   List(allFontNames, id: \.self) { name in
     Text(name)
       .font(Font.custom(name, size: 12))
   }
 }
```

[Source for iOS code](https://swiftuirecipes.com/blog/list-available-fonts-in-swiftui)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example using [`NSFontManager`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsfontmanager):

```swift
struct FontView: View {
    let allFontNames = NSFontManager.shared.availableFonts
    var body: some View {
        List(allFontNames, id: \.self) { name in
            Text(name).font(Font.custom(name, size: 12))
        }
    }
}
```